# How can I build android emulator in Linux and launch emulator in WINDOWS?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

**Is there a way I can build android emulator from AOSP source and run it in WINDOWS environment?**

I can build it from AOSP source in Linux environment and launch it in the same place without problem, but I don't know how to launch it in WINDOWS environment.

I tried to use my xxx.img instead of emulator image of Android studio,
but it doesn't work. It can not boot up.

Comment: I don't think you are building emulator. Emulator is what you run the result of the building process on.

Comment: It should be building the image which running in emulator. sorry for confusion.

Comment: found any solution? I'm also in the need of building the source in linux and copy the emulator to windows and run the emulator in windows.